# Exporting jest config with next/jest yields issue with async code

Tags: next.js, jestjs, commonjs

I'm facing an issue exporting Jest configurations in a Next project, I'm following [the Next 14 docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/testing/jest). This is my `jest.config.js`:

```
const nextJest = require("next/jest")
const createJestConfig = nextJest({dir: "./"})
const config = {
    coverageProvider: "babel",
    preset: "ts-jest",
    testEnvironment: "jest-environment-jsdom",
}
module.exports = createJestConfig(config)
```

I get this error in console (which in CommonJS means I'm trying to export an undefined variable):

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1')
at module.exports (/home/ldm-acn/gedi_drupal/gedi-fe-rsc/next.config.js:16:39)
```

The return value of `createJestConfig` is an unresolved promise, in the docs the export line is commented with `createJestConfig is exported this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js config which is async`, but it seems something is not working right.

Btw, if I export the `config` object directly I get no error, but I also miss on Next taking charge of loading my env files, etc.

**Should I change something in my jest configuration? Should I check other configuration files to make sure other options are set properly?**